# How to find the magento current edition with magento admin panel

Tags: version-upgrade, magento2-4-5

I have tried upgrading my client website from Magento 2.3.6 -p1 to 2.4.5-p1

For that, I have admin access to Magento 2.3.6 and when I hit the URL like the following command, I got an output like this...

[image]

Can you please confirm what command do I need to run for version upgrade
**Either this**

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.5-p1 --no-update

                         **or**
composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition=2.4.5-p1 --no-update
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the content of the file called composer.json. It is stored in the root of your Magento installation. In that file there is a line stored inside "require" which indicates which type and version of Magento is used.

Answer (score 0):

This one you have to run as it is a community version.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.5-p1 --no-update
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the screendump it seems to me you are using the enterprise version of Magento 2.3. In that case you should use enterprise-edition. I doubt if you could update from 2.3.6 directly to 2.4.5-p1 though.